# Create module, then import said module

Tags: python, import, module

I am trying to create a module and import it into another program.
My task for the module is for it to:

- accept a string
- have a docstring explaining what it does
- return the count of how many letters are in the string parameter

I was able to create the module, and I *think* it should return the correct count, but I am either having trouble implementing it into my original code, or the code in my new module file is wrong as well.

Here is the code from the original file:

```
# Program for Determining Palindromes

import stack
import letterCount
from letterCount import countLetters

# welcome
print ('This program can determine if a given string is a palindrome\n')
print ('(Enter return to exit)')

# init
char_stack = stack.getStack()
empty_string = ''

# get string from user
chars = input('Enter string to check: ')

while chars != empty_string:
    if len(chars) == 1:
        print('A one letter word is by definition a palindrome\n')
    else:
        # init
        is_palindrome = True

        # determine half of length. excluding any middle character
        compare_length = len(chars) // 2

        # push second half of input string on stack
        for k in range(compare_length, len(chars)):
            stack.push(char_stack, chars[k])

        # pop chars and compare to first half of string
        k = 0
        while k < compare_length and is_palindrome:
            ch = stack.pop(char_stack)
            if chars[k].lower() != ch.lower():
                is_palindrome = False

            k = k + 1

        # display results
        if is_palindrome:
            print (chars, 'is a palindrome\n')
            print (
        else:
            print (chars, 'is NOT a palindrome\n')

    # get string from user
    chars = input('Enter string to check: ')
```

and here is the code for the module I created:

```
def countLetters(chars):
    """this function keeps track of the longest palindrome"""
    palinlen = len(chars)

    print("This Palindrome is ",palinlen," characters long!")
```

What exactly am I missing? Any help would be **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual issue is, but you can use letterCount.countLetters('enter your string here')

Comment: Why do you think you're having trouble? Do you get errors? Do you get unexpected output?

Comment: If you have a traceback, please provide.

Comment: You never call `countLetters` after importing it, which means that you never invoke it. Pedantically, the function/module itself technically doesn't `return` anything, it only does a `print()`, when you say you want it to return. Also, according to PEP guidelines, functions should be named using snake_case, all lowercase with underscores, not mixed case like you have

Answer (score 1):

You fail to actually call the function you have imported.

The comments on your question already explain this, but to go into a little more detail:

Say we have 2 files, one is my 'module', the other my project (this is a useless example btw)

```
#Module file, moduleFoo.py
def foo(bar):
    print(bar)
```

.

```
#Project file
import moduleFoo
moduleFoo.foo("Some wild stuff")
```

With the final line of our project file, we *call* or *invoke* our function inside the module file

This can also be done doing:

```
from moduleFoo import foo
foo("Some wild stuff")
```